# Jquery UI tab: content in tab 2 is reflected in tab 1,instead of tab 2

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I created 2 tab using Jquery UI tab. When I manipulate data at tab 2,the tab 2 should retrieve the updated data and display the new data on tab 2. However, now, the updated data is shown on tab 1 and never reflect on tab 2. 
Is there any way to tell which tab the updated data should display on? 
I have been trying to find a way but has no luck so far. I am pretty new to javascript and jquery. Please help. 
Thank a lot.

Edit: my code is sth like this. It is as simple as what it is shown in official site.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="abc.php">test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="xyz.php">test2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Edit: I found the error. It is not in tab but in iframe.

Comment: i think there are some selector problem, can you please put your js & tab code in your question or if any external link?